# Magento 2 : Field depends in system.xml when fields are not in the same group

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml

How can you set `<depends>` for a field which is not in the same group of fields

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="200" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Name</label>
            <tab>tabname</tab>
            <resource>Namespace_ModuleName::method</resource>
            <group id="group" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="field" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="connection" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Connection Configuration</label>
                <field id="disable_certificate_check" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Check</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="field">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Field id from depends node must contain section, group and field id's of the field you want to depend

```
<depends>
    <field id="section_id/group_id/field_id">1</field>
</depends>
```

Comment: Yes , try same way , but when in select "No" from the first group then hide both groups, can you please elaborate your answer on more.

Comment: @St3phan, How can we hide a whole group?

Comment: [@mshakeel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/56221/mshakeel), I do not know if it can but let me have a little time to test.

Comment: @St3phan, did it using Javascript (answered). Share if you find a proper way.

Comment: You can use your jQuery code, sure.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="your_id" translate="label" sortOrder="1000">
            <label>your_label</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="your_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="340" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>your_label</label>
            <tab>your_tab</tab>
            <resource>Your_Module::config</resource>
            <group id="your_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>your_label</label>
                <field id="your_id" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>your_label</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="your_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>your_label</label>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="*/*/active">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
                <field id="your_id" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>your_label</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                     <depends>
                        <field id="*/*/active">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="your_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>your_label</label>
                <field id="your_id" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>your_label</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>               
                <depends>
                    <field id="section_id/group_id/field_id">1</field>
                </depends>
            </group>



        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hide Configuration Groups**

For magento 2.1.x, you can use following jQuery to toggle dependent Configuration Groups:

```
<comment><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    require(['jquery'], function(){
        if (jQuery('#field_id').val() == 'value_to_compare') {
            toggleDependantGroups(true);
        }

        jQuery('#field_id').change(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).val() == 'value_to_compare') {
                toggleDependantGroups(true);
            } else {
                toggleDependantGroups(false);
            }
        });

        function toggleDependantGroups(hide=true)
        {
            if (hide) {
                jQuery('#section-id').closest('div.section-config').hide();
                jQuery('#section-id').closest('div.section-config').hide();
                jQuery('#last-visible-section-id').closest('div.section-config').css('border-bottom-width', '0px');
            } else {
                jQuery('#section-id').closest('div.section-config').show();
                jQuery('#section-id').closest('div.section-config').show();
                jQuery('#last-visible-section-id').closest('div.section-config').css('border-bottom-width', '1px');
            }
        }
    });
</script>]]>
```

Replace ids where necessary.

Comment: where to write this script? in which file?

Comment: Yes, what js file supports a system.xml layout definition?